# How to calculate error of calculated integral in python?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, montecarlo, integral

I am calculating an integral with the Monte-Carlo-Method (for 3 different N's 10, 100, 1000), but I want to calculate the error to the real exact value of the integral (calculated analytically). How to do that? How to calculate the real value of the integral, and plot&print the error value?

Here is the code I am using now, to calculate the integral with the Monte-Carlo-Method:

```
a = 0
b = 2
N = np.array([10, 100, 1000])

def func(x):
    return np.power(sin(1/(x*(2-x))),2)

areas = []

j = 0
while j < len(N):

    for i in range(N[j]):

        xrandom = np.random.uniform(a,b,N[j])

        integral = 0.0

        for i in range(N[j]):
            integral += func(xrandom[i])

        result = (b-a)/float(N[j]) * integral
        areas.append(result)

    plt.subplot(1,3,j+1)
    plt.hist(areas, bins=30, ec='black')
    j += 1

fig = plt.gcf()   
fig.set_size_inches(12.5, 5.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is your question "how do you integrate this function"? Because I don't think that belongs on this SE...

Comment: Wolfram won't provide integral, but compute value of it `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%5E2(1%2F(x*(2-x)))+dx+from+0+to+2` Answer is 1.4514

Comment: @Engineero my question is, how to calculate the error, between the numerically calculated integral with Monte-Carlo (which I am calculating) and that the real integral, and how to plot the error and its evolution, as the number of random numbers (N in this example) grow.

Comment: You might be able to get an exact integral with a symbolic math package in Python, but in general any Python library that calculates the integral of a function will do so numerically. That goes for just about every computational package out there, including Wolfram, although Wolfram will try to give you the exact expression as well, which you could evaluate. That numeric method may be more or less accurate than MC, but regardless, it is necessarily not *exact*.

Comment: My suggestion, if you truly need the *exact* integral, is to figure out the exact form on paper and make a separate function that calculates the value of the integral over whatever range you are interested in.

Comment: That solution with the symbolic math package would be nice :-) And do you have an idea, if it is asked in an assignment, to calculate the error between the integral calculated with MC and the real value of the integral, how to proceed? How to program that? I won't be giving back a piece of paper unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`scipy.integrate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html), which offers different methods of calculating the integral. e.g.:

```
scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: func(x), a, b)
```

Comment: @user6655984 the issue is that the specific function OP is using doesn't have an elementary antiderivative, so numerical approximations are the best we can do.

Comment: One of the output parameters, `abserr`, of the [`quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) function provides an estimate of the absolute error in the integration.